# Type casting after initialise a view

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, view

```
struct ViewOne<T>: View{
    let value: T

    var body: some View{
        makeBody()
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func makeBody(){
        if T is Text{
            T
        }else if T is String{
            Text(T)
        }else if T is Color{
            T.opacity(0.3).ignoreSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make a View accepts a generic type T, and the view renders depends on what protocol that T conforms to. Type specific functions should be accessible. Thanks :)

Comment: No you don't. This would require way more work than what you get in return. And your sample code has nothing to do with protocols and will not compile

Comment: Look at the initializers for something like a “Button” you can mimic from there and then unwrap with a switch or “if let” but SwiftUI views aren’t like other objects this is not a “normal” approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `T is Blah` tests aren't sufficient. You don't just need to see if `T` is a `Blah`. You need to get `value` **as** a `Blah` if its type is `Blah`. That requires a `value as? Blah` cast or a `value as Blah` pattern.

Using casts:

```
@ViewBuilder
func makeBody() -> some View {
    if let text = value as? Text {
        text
    } else if let string = value as? String {
        Text(string)
    }else if let color = value as? Color {
        color.opacity(0.3).ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Using patterns:

```
@ViewBuilder
func makeBody() -> some View {
    switch value {
    case let text as Text:
        text
    case let string as String:
        Text(string)
    case let color as Color:
        color.opacity(0.3).ignoresSafeArea()
    default:
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```